# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://russian.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Thanks to anyone who voted - for me or for other candidates. I'm actually excited since whatever small the absolute numbers are (still a small community) never in my life anyone voted for me. Well, partially, I guess, due to the fact that I never participated in any kind of elections but again I'm still very excited )

Comment: @shabunc I see that one of the side-effects of having election chatroom was that [the main room was frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3764/2021/11/3). Maybe the moderators would be willing to unfreeze it.